# Google maps places api: Why do they need adsense publisher id?

Tags: api, google-maps, adsense

I am trying to use places api for google map on my website. As the manual (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) says it needs registration and the registration needs adsense publisher id. What is the point why should I have adsense to use maps?

Comment: It does **NOT** say that you need adSense to use maps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document says

> Additionally, calculation of Place information may generate ... advertising which must be displayed to the user in some fashion.

and maybe that's served to you through AdSense. But it seems odd to me, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In places API of the Google map you are indirectly advertising for that place. Also, that place appears the search of google local business search.

So that may be Googles view for getting the adsense. As google is also doing business. That might be there strategy to generate revenue or future business plan.

Comment: Sure, they're showing adverts but why would you need an account? The only reasons for you to have an account is either they're going to pay you for showing the adds - and if they're in it for the revenue then they might as well keep that for themselves - or if they're reusing the adsense mechanism to serve the ads in the first place.