# Is it possible to use Google Places API without Adsense Publishes ID in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to develop an Android application to find the nearest locations using Google Places API. While registration process, I came across the need of Adsense Publisher ID. Is it possible to use Google Places API without Adsense Publisher ID in Android?

Comment: Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448687/google-maps-places-api-why-do-they-need-adsense-publisher-id

Comment: My app is not a Website based one. Then why Adsense Publisher ID is mandatory? :(

Answer (score 0):

We opened up the Google Places API this week at Google I/O and an Adsense publisher ID is no longer required. For more information see:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/places-everybody-show-is-about-to-begin.html

Many thanks,

Thor